# Sort based on Characters(String) Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have array of objects. Here i need to sort value while binding.

simple.ts

```
this.data =  
      [
         {
            name : 'C1A5'
         },
         {
            name : 'C1A1'
         },
         {
            name : 'C1A2'
         },
         {
            name : 'C1A4'
         },
         {
            name : 'C1A3'
         },
         {
            name : 'C1A7'
         },
         {
            name : 'C1A6'
         }
      ]
```

simple.html

```
 <div class="" *ngFor="let d of data">
      {{d.name}}
</div>
```

Here how can I sort to get below result in UI:

```
 'C1A1'
    'C1A2'
    'C1A3'
    'C1A4'
    'C1A5'
    'C1A6'
    'C1A7'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner solution, one of the ways to sort it would be to make use of [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) on your comparison function.

```
this.data.sort((a, b) => a['name'].localeCompare(b['name']));
```

Also, please tag your question with the appropriate tags. This is a general JavaScript question, hence you should tag it with 'JavaScript' instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .sort() for sorting array like javascript style in angular

```
this.data.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.name - b.name;
});
```